# Array range error - classic ASP

Tags: arrays, vbscript, asp-classic

I am a beginner in Classic ASP. Need to split a string that is formed of many emails delimited by comma and the result to insert (email by email) in a table using additional code I will produce later on. Each record should have a single email address.
Problem is I am stuck in an array range error. The message is:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009'
>
> Subscript out of range: 'WrdArray'
>
> /NameOfFile.asp, line 3

Any hint will be highly appreciated.

```
Dim WrdArray()  
Dim txtToSplit 
WrdArray() = Split(txtToSplit,",")  
For i = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)  
  strg = WrdArray(i)
  'CODE TO INSERT THE VALUE OF strg IN A RECORD OF THE TABLE
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a dynamic array here, just remove the `()` to declare a standard variable that will become a variant array when `Split()` is called.

```
Dim WrdArray
Dim txtToSplit 
WrdArray = Split(txtToSplit,",")  
For i = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)  
  strg = WrdArray(i)
  'CODE TO INSERT THE VALUE OF strg IN A RECORD OF THE TABLE
Next
```

Dynamic array declarations are used when you need to increase the size of the array at runtime using the `ReDim` command. In this case `Split()` will always return a fixed number of results so there is no need to use a dynamic array unless you plan on adding more items later.